# Create a list of all possible Boolean configurations of three constraints

Tags: list-manipulation, boolean-computation

I have three nonnegativity constraints
\begin{equation}
A_1>0, A_2>0, A_3>0.
\end{equation}
I want to create a single List consisting of all possible/inequivalent Boolean configurations of none (trivial), one (also trivial), two, and three of them, using the AND, NOT and OR operations.

How long will this List be?

Well--in response to the initial comment/answer--I was really thinking of a (multi-element) List  such as

```
{B1 && B2 && ! B3, B1 || (B2 && B3), ! (B1 && B2) && B3,  B1 || (! B2 && B3), B1 || ! (B2 && B3), ! B1 && B2 && B3}
```

Given such a List, I would make the substitutions

```
{B1 -> A1 > 0, B2 -> A2 > 0, B3 -> A3 > 0}
```

and then attempt Boolean integrations using Boole[each element of the resulting list].

Comment: Are there any equivalent pairs in this list? `res = And @@ MapThread[Construct, {#, {a, b, c}}] & /@ 
   Tuples[{Not, Identity}, 3];
res = Join[res, Not /@ res];`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`BooleanCountingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanCountingFunction.html):

```
exp = Array[Subscript[A, #] > 0 &, 3];
BooleanConvert[BooleanCountingFunction[{1}, 3] @@ exp]

TeXForm @ %
```

> $\small\left(A_1\leq 0\land A_2\leq 0\land A_3>0\right)\lor \left(A_1\leq 0\land A_2>0\land A_3\leq 0\right)\lor \left(A_1>0\land A_2\leq 0\land
>    A_3\leq 0\right)$

```
BooleanConvert[BooleanCountingFunction[{2}, 3] @@ exp] // TeXForm
```

> $\small \left(A_1\leq 0\land A_2>0\land A_3>0\right)\lor \left(A_1>0\land A_2\leq 0\land A_3>0\right)\lor \left(A_1>0\land A_2>0\land A_3\leq
>    0\right)$

```
BooleanConvert[BooleanCountingFunction[{3}, 3] @@ exp] // TeXForm
```

> $\small A_1>0\land A_2>0\land A_3>0$

Answer (score 3):

You can create a list of all 8 possible combinations:

```
tups = Tuples[And[{B1, !B1}, {B2, !B2}, {B3, !B3}]]
```

> {B1 && B2 && B3, B1 && B2 && ! B3, B1 && ! B2 && B3, 
>    B1 && ! B2 && ! B3, ! B1 && B2 && B3, ! B1 && B2 && ! B3, ! B1 && ! B2 && 
>     B3, ! B1 && ! B2 && ! B3}

Then, I think you want the power set:

```
sets = BooleanMinimize /@ Subsets[Or @@ tups];
sets[[;;20]]
```

> {False, B1 && B2 && B3, B1 && B2 && ! B3, B1 && ! B2 && B3, 
>    B1 && ! B2 && ! B3, ! B1 && B2 && B3, ! B1 && B2 && ! B3, ! B1 && ! B2 && 
>     B3, ! B1 && ! B2 && ! B3, B1 && B2, 
>    B1 && B3, (B1 && B2 && B3) || (B1 && ! B2 && ! B3), 
>    B2 && B3, (B1 && B2 && B3) || (! B1 && B2 && ! B3), (B1 && B2 && 
>       B3) || (! B1 && ! B2 && B3), (B1 && B2 && 
>       B3) || (! B1 && ! B2 && ! B3), (B1 && B2 && ! B3) || (B1 && ! B2 && B3), 
>    B1 && ! B3, (B1 && B2 && ! B3) || (! B1 && B2 && B3), B2 && ! B3}

You examples are all included:

```
examples = {
    B1 && B2 && ! B3,
    B1 || (B2 && B3),
    ! (B1 && B2) && B3, 
    B1 || (! B2 && B3),
    B1 || ! (B2 && B3),
    ! B1 && B2 && B3
};
MemberQ[sets, #]& /@ BooleanMinimize /@ examples
```

> {True, True, True, True, True, True}

Comment: Thanks! I don't think I was considering more than 3 member combinations (hard enough to integrate with them as constraints)--but some of those (at most three) member combinations would have OR's in them--such as B1 || (B2 && B3). I don't see that standing by itself in your list (or any other two- or three-member group with an imbedded OR). Why is its presence tested as TRUE? Not sure as to the conversion rules of Boolean operations--can parentheses be removed? That's why I posted the question--to try to efficiently list all three-member distinct possibilities for my integration computations.

Comment: @PaulB.Slater I only showed the first 20 of the 256 elements of the power set. I don't understnad your criteria for what elements of the power set you want to consider.

Comment: Thanks again! I do now see the full 256 entries. How can I select those among them with n B's in them (n=2, 3, 4,...)? That seem like a resonable order in which to attempt my constrained integrations.